# Can not streaming resource with Microsoft Edge

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using java JSF and primefaces component to to read and show a PDF file. How I read file:

```
File file = new File(path);

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    download = null;
}

if (fis != null) {   
    download = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                    .name("checklist.pdf")
                    .contentType("pdf")
                    .stream(() -> fis)
                    .build();

PrimeFaces instance = PrimeFaces.current();
instance.ajax().update("menuForm:urServiceRequestDialog");   
instance.executeScript("PF('widgetUrServiceRequestDialog').show()");
```

On PrimeFaces site display it as a pdf in media component:

```
<p:commandButton process="@form" widgetVar="widgetChecklistButton" actionListener="#{urServiceRequestControler.showChecklist(urEntryControler.selectedStopRegister)}"/>

<p:panel>  
    <div class="card">
       <p:media value="#{urServiceRequestControler.download}" cache="false" player="pdf">
           Brak pliku PDF.
       </p:media>
    </div>
</p:panel>
```

On Firefox, Chrome it works fine. The issue is when I try to run it on Microsoft Edge. Then get a error like belo:

```
[2024-01-18T12:56:15.741+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] 
[javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1705578975741] [levelValue: 900] [[
StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces 
Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Error in streaming dynamic resource. Verify you are not using a @ViewScoped bean.
```

Tested in all possible scopes. What can be a reason?

Comment: You could use PrimeFaces Extensions PDF Viewer if you want bulletProof PDF's no matter the broswer: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf